# Hide badge in BadgeBox in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
BadgeBox(badgeContent = { Text("8") }) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Favorite,
        contentDescription = "Favorite"
    )
}
```

I have a `BadgeBox` like this. But if the value is `0`, I want to badge to disappear. If I pass null to `badgeContent`, the circle still shows but with nothing in it.

How do I hide it completely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [**1.1.0**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material?hl=he#1.1.0-alpha01) `Badge` has been moved from `BadgeBox`, so if you're using Compose version **1.1.x** or newer, you can use it as follows:

```
BadgedBox(
    badge = {
        if (count > 0) {
            Badge {
                Text("$count")
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Favorite,
        contentDescription = "Favorite"
    )
}
```

---

Solution for version **1.0.x**.

You can specify `backgroundColor` to transparent color when you don't need to display the badge:

```
BadgeBox(
    badgeContent = {
        if (count > 0) {
            Text("$count")
        }
    },
    backgroundColor = if (count > 0) MaterialTheme.colors.error else Color.Transparent
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Favorite,
        contentDescription = "Favorite"
    )
}
```

Comment: It is available in ' // Compose Material Design
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'